# A challenge-find the shortest solution!

Tags: chess, optimization

I come here with the challenge today-find the shortest solution!

Recently, I set out to created the longest [helpmate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helpmate) possible, not caring for legality or duals I have created this monster as a result.

Black To Move-Helpmate In How Many Moves?

[image]

This is today's task-try to find the quickest way to achieve the goal! Remember, White pawns move up and Black pawns move down, and all pieces move normally. Contrary to most of my other questions, **computers** and any other means are **allowed** for this puzzle. May you solve it with fun!

Comment: Well, I can guess black's first move! ;P

Comment: I have made a [lichess study](https://lichess.org/study/rFiFqozI) for ease of analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the par on this course? I can do it in

> 106 moves

moves. My strategy is to

> run the black king down to get the bishop then back up with the white king and switch places then back down for the mate.

Here's the Lichess link: [Link](https://lichess.org/N4SdtCyD#211)

And also, here's the PGN for the answer. Note that black has only one legal move in the beginning - Kh7, and that is where the PGN starts:

> ```
> [Variant "From Position"]
> [FEN "1b3b2/b1p1p1bk/1bPbPp1p/b1pPpPbP/1bPpPpBb/b1pBpPp1/1bPbPbP1/b1b1bB1K !w - - 0 1"]
> 1. Bh3 Kg8 2. Bg4 Bh8 3. Bh3 Bfg7 4. Bg4 Kf8
> 5. Bh3 Ke8 6. Bg4 Kd8 7. Bh3 Kc8 8. Bg4 Bg1
> 9. Kxg1 Bf2+ 10. Kh1 Bg1 11. Kxg1 Be1 12. Kh1 Bf2
> 13. Bh3 Bd2 14. Bg4 Bbc1 15. Bh3 Bde1 16. Bg4 Bcd2
> 17. Bh3 Bac1 18. Bg4 Bba3 19. Bh3 B5b4 20. Bg4 B6a5
> 21. Bh3 B7b6 22. Bg4 B8a7 23. Bh3 Bg1 24. Kxg1 Bf2+
> 25. Kh1 Bg1 26. Bg4 Be1 27. Bh3 Bcd2 28. Kxg1 Bf2+
> 29. Kh1 Bac1 30. Bg4 Bba3 31. Bh3 B5b4 32. Bg4 B6a5
> 33. Bh3 B7b6 34. Bg4 Bg1 35. Kxg1 Be1 36. Kh1 Bf2
> 37. Bh3 Bd2 38. Bg4 Bac1 39. Bh3 Bba3 40. Bg4 B5b4
> 41. Bh3 Kb8 42. Bg4 Ka7 43. Bh3 Ka6 44. Bg4 Ka5
> 45. Bh3 Ka4 46. Bg4 Bg1 47. Kxg1 Be1 48. Bh3 Bf2+
> 49. Kh1 Bd2 50. Bg4 Bac1 51. Bh3 Bg1 52. Kxg1 Be1
> 53. Kh1 Bf2 54. Bg4 Bd2 55. Bh3 Ka3 56. Bg4 Kb2
> 57. Bh3 Kc1 58. Bg4 Kd1 59. Bh3 Ke1 60. Bg4 Kxf1
> 61. Bh3 Ke1 62. Bg4 Bg1 63. Kxg1 Kd1 64. Kf1 Be1
> 65. Bh3 Kc1 66. Kxe1 Kb2 67. Kd1 Ka3 68. Kc1 Ka4
> 69. Kb1 Ka5 70. Ka2 Ka6 71. Kb3 Ka7 72. Ka4 Kb8
> 73. Kb5 Kc8 74. Ka6 Kd8 75. Kb7 Ke8 76. Kc8 Kf8
> 77. Kd8 Kg8 78. Ke8 Bf8 79. Bg4 Kh7 80. Kxf8 Bg7+
> 81. Kf7 Kh8 82. Kg6 Kg8 83. Bh3 Kf8 84. Bg4 Ke8
> 85. Bh3 Kd8 86. Kf7 Kc8 87. Ke8 Kb8 88. Kd8 Ka7
> 89. Kc8 Ka6 90. Bg4 Ka5 91. Kb7 Ka4 92. Ka6 Ka3
> 93. Kb5 Kb2 94. Ka4 Kc1 95. Kb3 Kd1 96. Ka2 Ke1
> 97. Kb1 Kf2 98. Kc1 Kxg2 99. Bh3+ Kh2 100. Bg2 Bb2+
> 101. Kd1 Ba1 102. Bh1 Kh3 103. Ke1 Bb2 104. Kf1 Ba1
> 105. Kg1 Bb2 106. Bg2#
> ```